# Include counts in as_json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Customers` table and an `Orders` table. Each customer has multiple orders. When I do a `Customers.all.as_json(:include => :orders)`, I get all the orders but I just want to get the count

I tried `Customers.all.as_json(:include => {:orders => {:only => [], :methods => [:custom_method_to_get_order_count}})` though it gets the correct count I have array of object that are equal to count.

**Wrong output! :(**

```
[
  {
    :customer_id => 1,
    :customer_name => "ABC",
    :orders => [
        {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 2},
        {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 2}
    ]
  },
  {
    :customer_id => 2,
    :customer_name => "DEF",
    :orders => [
        {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 3},
        {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 3},
        {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 3}
    ]
  },
  {
      :customer_id => 3,
      :customer_name => "XYZ",
      :orders => [
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10},
          {:custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10}
      ]
  }
]
```

Correct output I am looking for

```
[
  {
    :customer_id => 1,
    :customer_name => "ABC",
    :orders => {
        :custom_method_to_get_order_count => 2
    }
  },
  {
    :customer_id => 2,
    :customer_name => "DEF",
    :orders => {
        :custom_method_to_get_order_count => 3
    }
  },
  {
      :customer_id => 3,
      :customer_name => "XYZ",
      :orders => {
        :custom_method_to_get_order_count => 10
      }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use like this:

```
class Customers

  def get_orders_count
    self.orders.count
  end

end
```

and now you can get all orders count in customer object:

```
Customers.all.as_json(method: :get_orders_count)
```

Output will be something like:

```
[
  {
    :customer_id => 1,
    :customer_name => "ABC",
    :get_orders_count => 12
  },
  {
    :customer_id => 2,
    :customer_name => "DEF",
    :get_orders_count => 20
  },
  {
      :customer_id => 3,
      :customer_name => "XYZ",
      :get_orders_count => 50
  }
]
```

Comment: This answer is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I got the answer.

```
class Customers

  def custom_method_to_get_order_count
    Orders.where(:customer_id => id).count
  end

end
```

What's happening to me, whenever I post the question on SO, I get the answer!